# Existe alguna manera de como acomodar los elementos sin modificar el html?

Tags: css, responsive

Debo hacerlo como esta en la imagen sin modificar el código html ya que ese código lo tengo para otras resoluciones entonces no puedo modificarlo.

[image: asi debe quedarme como esta en la imagen]

lo que pasa es que hice la resolución de `1280px` y la de `768px` ahora con la de `320px` tengo que hacer otro tipo de maquetación entonces se me esta complicando (debe quedarme como la imagen).

```
<section class="ciudades">
  <div class="ciudad__contenido">
    <h2 class="ciudad__contenido-title">Kiev, Ucrania</h2>
    <img class="ciudad__contenido-image" src="imagenes/__Ucrania.png" alt="Ucrania" />

    <button class="ciudad__contenido-boton">
      Compra esta obra de arte como NFT
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="ciudad__descripcion">
    <p class="ciudad__contenido-artista">ARTISTA</p>
    <h3 class="ciudad__contenido-nombre">
      Natalia Dolgushina, productora de contenidos
    </h3>
    <p class="ciudad__contenido-text">
      Kiev (o Kyiv), la capital de ciudad, es una gran ciudad situada a
      orillas del río Dniéper. Por supuesto, nadie en su sano juicio se
      bañaría en el río, a menos que se haya criado aquí, en cuyo caso
      probablemente lo haya intentado en algún momento. Los veranos son
      calurosos aquí, y los inviernos con fuertes corrientes de aire,
      pero el otoño y la primavera son absolutamente increíbles.
    </p>
    <p class="ciudad__contenido-text2">
      La ciudad en sí es una mezcla de arquitectura prerrevolucionaria,
      de posguerra y soviética, toda ella salpicada de balcones
      modificados. Si te encuentras en la orilla derecha del Dniéper, el
      paisaje es difícil de atravesar para las personas en bicicleta y
      las que llevan tacones. Sin embargo, la orilla izquierda es
      considerada mucho menos interesante y prestigiosa, incluso por la
      gente que vive en las afueras de la derecha.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Esto es lo que he trabajado en **CSS** pero no encontrado una solución.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .header__logo1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 51.852px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    margin-top: 2rem;
  }

  .patria {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .patria__contenido-title {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 104.167%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 288px;
  }

  .patria__contenido-subtitle {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 5;
    line-height: 125%;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
  }

  .patria__contenido-image {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    margin-bottom: 0%;
  }

  .introduccion__contenido {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
  }

  .introduccion__contenido-title {
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0% 5%;
    width: 88%;
  }
  .introduccion__contenido-text {
    margin-left: 24%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 91%;
  }

  .introduccion__contenido-footer {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 26px;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 26%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    font-weight: 100;
  }

  .introduccion_contenido-text2 {
    width: 90%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 4%;
    line-height: 30.08px;
  }

  .galeria__contenido {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 62px;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .ciudades {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .ciudad__contenido-title {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 109.375%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: -45%;
  }

  .ciudad__contenido-artista {
    color: #aaa;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 5;
    line-height: 125%;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }

  .ciudad__contenido-nombre {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 50;
    line-height: 125%;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
  }
  .ciudad__contenido-image {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    max-width: 320px;
  }

  .ciudad__contenido-text {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 5;
    text-align: inherit;
    line-height: 135%;
    max-width: 93%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  .ciudad__contenido-text2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 5;
    line-height: 135%;
    max-width: 93%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .ciudad__contenido-boton {
    width: 288px;
    height: 48px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #0278fe;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 3%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .visitanos__contenido {
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 254px;
  }

  .visitanos__contenido-image {
    background: #2a2c2f;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 15%;
  }

  .visitanos__contenido-image:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  .visitanos__contenido-title {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  .visitanos__contenido-subtitle {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    line-height: 125%;
    font-stretch: condensed;
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 45%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  .visitanos__contenido-boton {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 25%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .visitanos__contenido-boton:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  .footer__contenido {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .footer__contenido-title {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
    font-weight: lighter;
  }
}
```

Debo mover el botón hacia la parte de abajo y la parte que dice Artista y el subtitulo debe estar en la parte superior, junto con el titulo mas abajo debe ir la imagen no quiero modificar el **HTML** ya que tengo dos resoluciones realizadas la de `1280px` y la de `678px` solo me falta la de *mobile* que es de `320px`.el resultado debe ser como esta en la imagen.

Comment: Buen día, sí, si hay forma de hacerlo. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: cual es esa forma ? si investigado pero no encontrado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un contenedor con `display : flex` puede usar la propiedad [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/order) para cambiar el orden en que se muestran sus items.

El problema es que tu tienes 2 subcontenedores que dividen el contenido `.ciudad__contenido` y  `.ciudad__descripcion`, a estos debes setearlos como `display: content` y olvidarte que existen para la resolución de 320px:

Ejemplo:

```css
.ciudades{
display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.ciudad__contenido, .ciudad__descripcion {
  display: contents;
}

.ciudad__contenido-artista{ order:2; }
.ciudad__contenido-nombre { order:3; }
.ciudad__contenido-image { order:4; }
.ciudad__contenido-text{ order:5; }
.ciudad__contenido-text2{ order:6; }
.ciudad__contenido-boton { order:7; }
```

```html
<section class="ciudades">
  <div class="ciudad__contenido">
    <h2 class="ciudad__contenido-title">Kiev, Ucrania</h2>
    <img
      class="ciudad__contenido-image"
      src="imagenes/__Ucrania.png"
      alt="Ucrania"
    />

    <button class="ciudad__contenido-boton">
      Compra esta obra de arte como NFT
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="ciudad__descripcion">
    <p class="ciudad__contenido-artista">ARTISTA</p>
    <h3 class="ciudad__contenido-nombre">
      Natalia Dolgushina, productora de contenidos
    </h3>
    <p class="ciudad__contenido-text">
      Kiev (o Kyiv), la capital de ciudad, es una gran ciudad situada a
      orillas del río Dniéper. Por supuesto, nadie en su sano juicio se
      bañaría en el río, a menos que se haya criado aquí, en cuyo caso
      probablemente lo haya intentado en algún momento. Los veranos son
      calurosos aquí, y los inviernos con fuertes corrientes de aire,
      pero el otoño y la primavera son absolutamente increíbles.
    </p>
    <p class="ciudad__contenido-text2">
      La ciudad en sí es una mezcla de arquitectura prerrevolucionaria,
      de posguerra y soviética, toda ella salpicada de balcones
      modificados. Si te encuentras en la orilla derecha del Dniéper, el
      paisaje es difícil de atravesar para las personas en bicicleta y
      las que llevan tacones. Sin embargo, la orilla izquierda es
      considerada mucho menos interesante y prestigiosa, incluso por la
      gente que vive en las afueras de la derecha.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Mil gracias amigo, esa fue la solución te agradezco mucho